# How can I report the test results from a TestNG/Maven/Jenkins tests, via Email and attach screenshot?

Tags: jenkins, reporting, screenshot, testng

I have some SeleniumWebdriver/TestNG/Maven/Java continuous integration tests, that I run in Jenkins.
Every time a test fails, a screenshot of the error is created.

How can I configure Jenkins to send an email to certain people and attach the screenshot upon failure?
The screenshot is located in this directory:

```
/mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/surefire-reports/
```

and its name is generated as a combination of a timestamp and the error that has occured, like this:

```
2013-7-6-12-1-30-UnabletolocateelementmethodlinktextselectorApprove.jpg
```

Screenshots arent automatically deleted, so there could be quite a few screenshots in that dir.

So, how can I make Jenkins send me the report with the screenshot attached?

OR Can I make TestNG do that? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, no need to work with Jenkins, it can be done within the code of the test itself.
Generate the screenshot as described here:

[Selenium Webdriver/TestNG/Maven/Xvfb - take screenshot on fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989363/selenium-webdriver-testng-maven-xvfb-take-screenshot-on-fail)

then install the Java Mail API and a SMTP mailer service on your computer and make your code send email with the screenshot as an attachment upon failure.